# Defining Netty4 dependency when using Fabric8 to deploy to JBoss Fuse

Tags: maven, jboss, netty, fuseesb, fabric8

I am attempting to deploy a simple camel route to a JBoss Fuse 6.2 instance; however I'm having problems correctly defining dependencies when I attempt to use a Netty4 endpoint.

I started with the basic blueprint archetype example:

**blueprint.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
    <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000"/>
    <log message="Message Received"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.co.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>messageprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>
  <properties>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <camel.plugin.version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</camel.plugin.version>
    <fabric8.version>1.2.0.redhat-133</fabric8.version>
    <fabric8.features>camel-jms activemq-camel</fabric8.features>
    <fabric8.featureRepos>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${version:camel}/xml/features</fabric8.featureRepos>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.2.0.redhat-133</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk.version}</source>
          <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>messageprocessor</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package>uk.co.example.messageprocessor.*</Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${fabric8.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

If I deploy using **fabric:deploy**, this works fine. I get a valid profile which can be added to a container and will log a message every 5 seconds as expected.

However, if I attempt to add a reference to Netty4, it fails. In JBoss Dev Studio I removed the the timer endpoint and replaced it with with Netty4.

**blueprint.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
      <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:9999"/>
      <log message="Message Received"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

This change automatically added a camel-netty4 dependency to the POM XML. I thought that in order to inform Fabric8 of this new dependency I would need to add this reference to the fabric8.features, so I did that.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.co.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>messageprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>
  <properties>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <camel.plugin.version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</camel.plugin.version>
    <fabric8.version>1.2.0.redhat-133</fabric8.version>
    <fabric8.features>camel-jms activemq-camel camel-netty4</fabric8.features>
    <fabric8.featureRepos>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${version:camel}/xml/features</fabric8.featureRepos>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.2.0.redhat-133</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-netty4</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk.version}</source>
          <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>messageprocessor</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package>uk.co.example.messageprocessor.*</Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${fabric8.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

However, if I build and redeploy, Fuse is unable to resolve the depencency. In the logs I see the following:

```
Bundle messageprocessor is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=netty4)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]

Unable to start blueprint container for bundle messageprocessor due to unresolved dependencies [(&(component=netty4)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:336)[org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.2]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_65]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_65]
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realised that my POM was overly complicated. In an attempt to appease the Developer Studio designer I had added Dependency Management. Once I regenerated the sample and tried again from a clear start point I ended up with a cleaner solution which works without the Dependency Manager.

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.co.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>messageprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>
  <properties>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <fabric8.profile>example-messageprocessor</fabric8.profile>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-netty4</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>messageprocessor</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package>uk.co.example.messageprocessor.*</Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.redhat-133</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This seems to work fine, though I did need to remove the explicit version definition against the maven-bundle-plugin.